# regex select words between two

Tags: regex

hi im using regex and notepad++
this code `"(\[[.*^[\x{0600}-\x{06FF}].*])` can find evey persian words that between []
if i want to find evey persian words between () what code can help?

Comment: Like this? `[[\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]+]|\([\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]+\)` https://regex101.com/r/8jYUYD/1

Comment: the secend one worked fine bt the first one work with some words try the first one on this[بازدارنده؛جلوگيرى‌كننده]

Comment: Does it contain a character not in that range?

Comment: yes the first one contain a character that not in rang or maybe cantain first words

Comment: what about if  i wnat exception the numbers in the codw?